# Unexpected [instance of 'model class'] error in flutter while working with TMDB Api

Tags: flutter, api, dart, deserialization

this is my model class

```
class TrendingModel {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? originalTitle;
  String? overview;
  String? posterPath;
  String? bannerPath;
  String? releaseDate;

  TrendingModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.originalTitle,
    this.overview,
    this.posterPath,
    this.bannerPath,
    this.releaseDate,
  });

  factory TrendingModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TrendingModel(
      bannerPath: json["backdrop_path"],
      id: json["id"],
      title: json["title"] ?? json["name"],
      originalTitle: json["original_title"],
      overview: json["overview"],
      posterPath: json["poster_path"],
      releaseDate: json["release_date"],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my HTTP call and deserialization. I need data inside the ["results"] list coming from TMDB API

my data is in this form
{"something" : value,
"result":[{"key": value,"key":"value"}]
}

```
class RemoteServices {
  Future<List<TrendingModel>?> getTrending() async {
    String uri =
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=(My api key)";
    var res =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["results"] as List;
      var movie = rest.map((e) => TrendingModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      print(movie);
      return movie;
    } else {
      throw Exception('faild to fetch');
    }
  }
}
```

when I print my response it shows this in the console

```
[Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel', Instance of 'TrendingModel']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to access something like : `movie[0].title`  as `TrendingModel` is main  class for parsing. And you have array of movie.
so if you want to access then `movie[index].key`